# How to ignore keys pushd

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc

I have a bash script in which it is necessary to specify keys and parameters. I created a command for it using alias.

```
alias command="pushd /path; ./somescript.sh; popd"
```

After the script does the work, I need to return to the directory from which the script was called.

But I get an error:

```
bash: popd: -o: invalid number
popd: using: popd [-n] [+N | -N]
```

Language of my sistem is not English, I'm sorry if in the original it looks differently.
What I should to do?

Comment: are you running that with `command -o` or such?

Comment: "I need to return to the directory from which the script was called". The script will not change your current directory in the interactive session.

Comment: Rather than `pushd` and `popd`, just `cd` in a subshell: `(cd /path; ./somescript)`. That won't help if you call `command -o` (for that, see ilkkachu's example of a function)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
$ alias foo="pushd /; ls -ld ./tmp; popd"
$ foo
/ ~
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root 4096 Dec 25 19:30 ./tmp/
~
```

But if you need to pass parameters to the middle command of the alias, you'll need to use a function instead. Otherwise the parameters are just added to the end of the alias, so they go as parameters to `popd`.

Do this instead:

```
something() {
    pushd /path > /dev/null
    ./somescript.sh "$@"
    popd > /dev/null
}
something -o blahblah
```

Using `command` as the name of the alias/function might not be the best call, it's a shell builtin that's used to call external commands, skipping functions with the same name.